# How to burn erc721 token?

Tags: nft, erc-721, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I am trying to burn erc721 token. I have inherited ERC721Burnable contract,but the transaction gets failed.While debugging I found that in ERC721URIStorage contract,it reverts back at:

```
if (bytes(_tokenURIs[tokenId]).length != 0) {
    delete _tokenURIs[tokenId];
}
```

.Also I want the owner of the contract to have the ability to modify the metadata.
This is my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Burnable, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;
    uint MAX_SUPPLY=1;

    constructor() ERC721("MyNFT", "MNFT") {}

    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        require(totalSupply() < MAX_SUPPLY, "Can be minted only one time.");
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure tokenId exists

Answer (score 0):

happens if the token of a specific tokenId is either not minted yet or minted and burnt already, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`EVM` is known for lack of clarity in tx reverted reasons. The source code of `_burn()` and `burn()` functions shows multiple places where a possible error could lead to reverted tx:

```
    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
        address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);

        _beforeTokenTransfer(owner, address(0), tokenId);

        // Update ownership in case tokenId was transferred by `_beforeTokenTransfer` hook
        owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);

        // Clear approvals
        delete _tokenApprovals[tokenId];

        unchecked {
            // Cannot overflow, as that would require more tokens to be burned/transferred
            // out than the owner initially received through minting and transferring in.
            _balances[owner] -= 1;
        }
        delete _owners[tokenId];

        emit Transfer(owner, address(0), tokenId);

        _afterTokenTransfer(owner, address(0), tokenId);
    }
```

```
function burn(uint256 tokenId) public virtual {
    //solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
    require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved");
    _burn(tokenId);
}
```

If you are sure your code fails at:

```
if (bytes(_tokenURIs[tokenId]).length != 0) {
    delete _tokenURIs[tokenId];
}
```

you need to double check at the stage of this block of code execution this entity `_tokenURIs[tokenId]` still exist.

Also I would propose to use hardhat as it has more clarity in tx reverted reason response and implement `_burn()` function on your contract to add log into console for debugging purpose which personally better helps me to spot the cause of the issue.